# Apache Ivy : " condition doesn't support the nested "javaversion" element. " error

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to configure a Jenkins job that compiles the code for Apache Ivy from the GIT repo. ( https://github.com/apache/ivy ) . I am getting the below error after running the job :

BUILD FAILED
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/apache-ivy/build.xml:28: condition doesn't support the nested "javaversion" element.

**Line 28 of build.xml**

`<condition property="java.sysprop.https.protocols" value="" else="TLSv1.2">
    <javaversion atleast="1.8"/>
</condition>`

I have set the global configuration to install apache ivy 1.10.1 to install automatically.

I have a Ubuntu EC2 instance running with openjdk-8-jdk installed.

Answer (score 1):

Use at least the `1.10.x` version of Ant. Go to `Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration` option to set the name and version. Also, ensure that your build looks like below[image]